# Ignoring spaces in length validation for JSON Schema

Tags: jsonschema

Say you have this simple schema

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "minLength": 2,
}
```

The value `"ab"` would be valid, but the value `"a "` or `"  "` would also be valid. Is there a way to ignore spaces when validating the length, so only `"ab"` is valid in this example?

Comment: You could use `pattern` and define something that excludes white space characters.

Comment: But that would make a string with spaces invalid, even if it satisfies the length without spaces

Comment: What jonrsharpe suggested would work as your question states you want to ignore white spaces.

Comment: No, my question states I want to ignore the spaces when validating the length of the value, not use a pattern to prevent the inclusion of spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
{
  "pattern": "^(\\s*\\w\\s*){2,}$"
}
```

"at least 2 groups where each group has exactly one non-space character (optionally surrounded by space characters)".

```
"" -> false
"  " -> false
"   " -> false
"  a" -> false
"a  " -> false
"  a  " -> false
"  a  b  " -> true
"ab" -> true
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, at least not with jsonschema (npm). I get an error no matter what.

Comment: You may need to escape the `\w` with `\\w` or something of that nature, depending on the language you are implementing.  This regex is a bit more open (allows 0-9 and _) than the one I proposed and is more explicit (anchored to start / end of the string).  If you are unfamiliar with regex, you probably will want to do some reading to be sure you are defining what you want.

Comment: That's about escaping indeed. See the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know enough about JSON schema to definitively say whether there is a way to do what you are asking with the length attribute.  However, if you have an idea of what possible non-whitespace characters are allowed, you can do something like the following that allows any number of white-space characters along with two required characters (in this case - alphabetic characters).

NOTE: I made the declaration inside an array for [easy testing](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/)

```
{
  "type": "array"
  , "items": {
      "type":"string"
      , "pattern": "[A-Za-z]\\s*[A-Za-z]"
  }
}
```

Some tests:

```
[
  "ab"
  , "a " // fails
  , "  " // fails
  , "cz"
  , "a    b"
  , "  a b"
  , "  b" // fails
]
```